# How to draw circles on a line and rotate them

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

Two questions about the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}  %%KOMA class
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}  %%

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [color=black!5] (0,0) grid (14,10);
 \draw (14,0) coordinate (a) node[right, below] {$x$}
       -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {(0,0)}
       -- (0,10) coordinate (c) node[left] {$y$};
 \draw [->, ultra thick] (0,2) coordinate (ad) node[left] {(0,2)}  -- (30:15cm) coordinate (dd)  node[above] {$l$};
 \draw (ad) -- (14,2)  coordinate (l);

 \path (ad) -- (dd) coordinate[pos=0.355](c1) coordinate[pos=0.692](c2);
 %circle A
 \draw [fill=red!15] (c1) circle [radius=2.365];
 %circle B
 \draw [fill=green!15] (c2) circle [radius=2.365];
 % centre  circles
 \draw (ad) -- (c1) node{$\bullet$} -- (c2) node {$\bullet$}--(dd)
 pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.1, angle radius=5cm]{angle=l--ad--dd}
 pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.1, angle radius=9.8cm]{angle=l--ad--dd};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

1. How do I calculate the second `coordinate[pos=0.692]` in terms of
   the circle radius `[radius=2.365]`?
2. How do I draw the rotation of the oblique line `l` as to center the  two circles on the `y=2` line at the correct position?
   [image]

The following almost fixes it (code to be cleaned):

```
 \coordinate
 let
 \p1=(ad),\p2=(c1),\p3=(c2),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},\n2={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)}
 in
 node (c1n) at (\n1,2) node (c2n) at (\n2,2);
 \draw [fill=red!25] (c1n) circle [radius=2.365];
 \draw [fill=green!25] (c2n) circle [radius=2.365];

 \draw
 let
 \p1=(ad),\p2=(c1),\p3=(c2),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},\n2={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)}
 in
 (ad) -- (c1n) node{$\bullet$} -- (c2n) node{$\bullet$} {}--(l)
 pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.05, angle radius=\n1]{angle=l--ad--dd}
 pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.02, angle radius=\n2]{angle=l--ad--dd};
 \draw (ad) -- (14,2)  coordinate (l);
```

[image]

Comment: Probably I'm slow/ignorant, but I don't understand what you want to do in point 2. Can you try to explain more thoroughly?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. pls. see new picture (which I draw by guessing the radius values of the two pics, which is not good). I wish to know if I may instruct tikz to calculate how to draw the two circles after rotation of line `l` from its present position to `y=2`. Am i clear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the features of the `calc` library for both problems. For 1., define the second coordinate as `\coordinate (c2) at ($(c1)!2*2.365 cm!(dd)$);`, i.e. the point that is twice the radius away from `c1`, towards `dd`.

For the second you can use the `let` syntax to calculate the distance from `dd` to each of the circle centers, and use that as the `angle radius`, and to define the center points of the two circles on the horizontal line.

I also added a second possible method for making the circles, by using `node`s with an appropriate `anchor` set.

Small note: I wouldn't use `\node {$\bullet$}` in the circle centers, as that is positioned a bit wrong. I used a filled, circular node instead, another option would be e.g. `\fill (c1) circle[radius=2pt];`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}  %%KOMA class
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}  %% 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,fill,draw}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [color=black!5] (0,0) grid (14,10);  
 \draw (14,0) coordinate (a) node[right, below] {$x$}
       -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {(0,0)} 
       -- (0,10) coordinate (c) node[left] {$y$};
 \draw [->, ultra thick] (0,2) coordinate (ad) node[left] {(0,2)}  -- (30:15cm) coordinate (dd)  node[above] {$l$};

 \path (ad) -- (dd) coordinate[pos=0.355](c1);
 \coordinate (c2) at ($(c1)!2*2.365 cm!(dd)$); 
 %circle A
 \draw [fill=red!15] (c1) circle [radius=2.365]; 
 %circle B
 \draw [fill=green!15] (c2) circle [radius=2.365]; 

 \path
 let
  \p1=(ad),\p2=(c1),\p3=(c2),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},\n2={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)}
 in
  (ad) ++(\n1,0) coordinate (c1n)
  (ad) ++(\n2,0) coordinate (c2n);

 \draw [fill=red!15] (c1n) circle [radius=2.365]; 
 %circle B
 \draw [fill=green!15] (c2n) circle [radius=2.365]; 


 \draw (ad) -- (14,2)  coordinate (l);
 % draw angles
 \draw 
  let
  \p1=(ad),\p2=(c1),\p3=(c2),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},\n2={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)}
   in
  (ad) -- (c1) node[bullet]{} -- (c2) node[bullet] {}--(dd)
   pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.05, angle radius=\n1]{angle=l--ad--dd}
   pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.02, angle radius=\n2]{angle=l--ad--dd};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
   alpha=25; % angle
   R=2.365cm; % radius
   L=14cm; % length of ray
   circpos=0.5; % position of circle tangent along ray
  },
  mycirc/.style={
   circle,
   draw=black,
   thin,
   fill=#1,
   minimum size=R*2,
   outer sep=0pt,
   label={[bullet]center:}
  }
]

 \draw [color=black!5] (0,0) grid (L,10);  
 \draw (L,0) coordinate (a) node[right, below] {$x$}
       -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {(0,0)} 
       -- (0,10) coordinate (c) node[left] {$y$};

 \draw [->, ultra thick] (0,2) coordinate (ad) node[left] {(0,2)}  -- ++(alpha:L) coordinate (dd)
  node[above] {$l$}
  node[mycirc=red!15,anchor=alpha,pos=circpos] (c1) {}
  node[mycirc=green!15,anchor=alpha+180,pos=circpos] (c2) {};

% draw second set of circles
 \path (ad) -- ++(0:L)
  node[mycirc=red!15,anchor=0,pos=circpos] {}
  node[mycirc=green!15,anchor=180,pos=circpos]  {};

 \draw (ad) -- (L,2)  coordinate (l);

 \draw (c1.alpha+180) -- (c2.alpha);

 \draw 
  let
  \p1=(ad),\p2=(c1.center),\p3=(c2.center),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},\n2={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)}
   in
   pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.05, angle radius=\n1]{angle=l--ad--dd}
   pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <<-, angle eccentricity=1.02, angle radius=\n2]{angle=l--ad--dd};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this fully answered your question ..

Comment: Op only asks how to set the center of the rightmost green circle, relatively to the left pink one, but it seems they actually want both circles to be tangent **in the middle of the `(ad)--(dd)` ray**. In that case, both `(c1)` and `(c2)` should be computed in the same way relatively to the middle.

Comment: @marsupilam Maybe you're right. mario: is that correct, should the circles meet at the exact midpoint of the line `l`?

Comment: I am checking. Also, how do convert to .png: I use `convert -density 300 0041.pdf -quality 100  0041a.png`, but your picture looks better, why?

Comment: @mario I just took a screenshot of the PDF ..

Comment: @marsupilan, no for my present case.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  Almost. See edit. I need to go, back in a couple of hours. thks.

Comment: @mario So you wanted a second pair of circles, that wasn't at all clear to me. I've updated the answer, see if that is better.

Comment: @  Torbjørn T.  Yes, it works beautyfully. Thks. Could you write a couple of lines  about the underlying math of `\p1=(ad),\p2=(c1),\p3=(c2),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},\n2={veclen(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)}`? Cheers

Comment: @mario Well, just Pythagoras I assume. `veclen(x,y)` calculates the length of a vector with components `x` and `y`.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T.  :-( yes of course!  In Tikz do I write: \p1=(a) \n=\x1 resp. \m=\y1 to store the first resp. second component of point (a) into \n resp. \m? (Guess I need to look at Tikz's manual)

Comment: @mario `\p1=(c1)` stores the x-coordinate of `c1` in `\x1`, and the y coordinate in `\y1`. `\nN` is for other calculations. But yes, have a look at the manual, chapter 14.15 *The Let Operation*.